# What will happen to my iOS app (currently live on the App Store) when I upgrade Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Been programming iOS apps for a few months and my first app is live on the App Store supported by a database hosted on Firebase. I'm storing data related to gluten-free places around the world on Firebase (name, address, latitue, longitude, imgURL etc.) and these places are then displayed on a Map.

Firebase released all their new features, I wanted to upgrade to start using their new Analytics modules. Now by reading [the upgrade guide](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-ios) I understand that there are a few things that we need to tweak in our code first.

So here is my concern (maybe dumb question but I want to be extra careful before doing stupid).

**Since my app is production on the App Store, if I upgrade my Firebase project, will my users still be able to use my app properly (i.e. getting the places displayed on the map) or will it break/bug/crash until I push an update to the App Store with an updated code based on Firebase's guide.**

Thanks in advance for your help guys.

Edouard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do think that it will not affect your current app unless you change the database model in web interface, or change the authentication rules in web interface.

Firebase frameworks actually pointing to the same server, and same database model right.

The new Firebase includes lot of features and new stuffs into the system, but still they do support the old frameworks. My app is currently running on the new Firebase web interface but using very old Firebase framework, it's not in production though.

But I can tell you that you can upgrade to the new Firebase even if your app is in App Store.

Comment: I've upgraded and I can confirm that there is no impact on the app that's currently on Production on the App Store.